# gem install mysql: Failed to build gem native extension (Mac Lion)

Tags: mysql, macos, compilation

I installed MySQL 5.5.27 for Mac OS X Lion (from .dmg).

Now i try to install the mysql gem:

```
$ gem install mysql
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/serg/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/serg/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-head/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-head/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-head/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okey, here is my solution:

```
1) I installed homebrew.
2) $ brew install mysql
3) $ gem install mysql
```

That is all.

Comment: on linux: `sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the gem installer can't find your MySQL libraries/headers.

Try specifying the MySQL directory, e.g.

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
```

(You might need to figure out where the DMG distribution of MySQL is installed, YMMV.)

Comment: You could giving the gem installer the path to mysql_config:

`gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work too:

`checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***`

Comment: On a Mac, with MySQL installed with brew, that'd be: `gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.32`. Adapt the path with what you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
```